# OpenCV stats possibilities

Tags: algorithm, opencv, statistics, histogram, gpgpu

I am currently having an algorithm that analyses input histogram in order to extract the most probable maximum value and also a delta, that determines which of the points nearby should be treated as same important. So what I need is to get the top part of certain random distribution graph. I was wondering if I can do it in a simple numeric way to make GPGPU options available (like OpenCV). 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear on what goal you are trying to achieve, but I think you are talking about using an image's histogram to enhance images / videos. (Intensity Transformations)  There are many ways to do this.

- Contrast enhancement (when you observe a narrow band of pixel intensities, and you want to enhance them across the entire intensity range.)
- Histogram Equalization (where you `broaden` the band width of the histogram to modify all pixels within an image, to generate a uniform histogram distribution)
- Histogram Transformation (where you modify pixel intensities to generate a non-uniform output with focus on particular bands of pixel intensity)
- Additionally there is a lot you can do with numeric filters to achieve a particular desired output.

OpenCV does include virtually all of the libraries for manipulating matrices in Matlab, and they do offer a library of tools that is accessible for the graphics card.

OpenCV on Graphic Processor Units (GPU's)
    1 hr Nvidia presentation:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKLDGCppInw
    Uses CUDA.  CUDA is a parallel computing platform and application programming interface (API) model created by NVIDIA.  This video is an excellent overview of OpenCV with CUDA...  According to that presentation, there is a 12x processing speed improvement for math heavy calculations using the CUDA tools with a graphics card in OpenCV.

```
    #include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>   (then use gpu:: namespace...)
```

Comment: Its not about the images. Just a random distribution analysis that should better be done GPU. Do you have any ideas on that topic?

Comment: @AshotVardanian  You can certainly use the Graphics Processor, but in this case you'd be limited to [the CUDA tools](http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html) (which is generally a majority of the normal OpenCV functions)  There's no magic here.  Use CUDA tools like you normally would use OpenCV functions, but things just work faster.  (think increased frame rates while processing every frame of a video...)  You can pretty much do any analysis you want.

Comment: Thanks for being active, however, I meant to ask if somebody has good sources/ existing solutions. Its obvious, that ones you have a numeric model you can put it on a GPGPU. I was asking about how you should transform all that histogram analysis to fit into matrixes and other structures to then pass it on the GPU.

Comment: Recommendation: Sign up for the free [Coursera Class "Image and video processing: From Mars to Hollywood with a stop at the hospital" from Duke University](https://www.coursera.org/course/images)   There is a huge discussion on Histogram and Spatial Processing in Week 3's lectures.  (Histogram modification, Histogram Equalization and Histogram matching.) These are all free video lectures.  Without know the EXACT specifics of what goal you are trying to achieve, I don't think anybody will have a specific recommendation for you.